# How to use the same route for multiple options (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, regex, laravel-5, controller, routes

I need to have a route for multiple pricing levels (`bronze`, `silver` and `gold`). Currently I have:

```
Route::get('/{level}', [ 'as' => 'pricing', 'uses' => 'PagesController@pricing']);
```

However, this matches anything, how can I make so it matches only: `bronze`, `silver` or `gold` while reading the value in my controller like this:

```
public function pricing($level) {
    $data['level'] = $level;
    return View::make('pages.pricing', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest just handling this inside the function using a `switch-case` statement (or `if/else`).

```
public function pricing() {
    switch ($level) {
        case 'silver':
            // do something
            break;
        case 'bronze':
            // do something
            break;
        case 'gold':
            // do something
            break;
        default:
            throw new \Exception('not one of bronze. silver or gold');
    }
}
```

However you could write

```
Route::get('/{level}', [ 'as' => 'pricing', 'uses' => 'PagesController@pricing'])->where('level', '(bronze|silver|gold)');
```